# Export plot form Rstudio into excel editable form?

Tags: r, excel, ggplot2, plot, gam

I have few plot from Generalized additive model(GAM) and MULTI variable additive models(MARs) including partials plots with 95% confidence index and a 3d plot of two most influential variable and its effect on output. The journal I'm submitting is asking for MS excel graphs and editable in MS excel. So how do I plot these the graphs in excel?

Export graphs in excel editable form, but ended in exporting in image form.

Comment: You may have a look at the `mscharts` package which via `openxlsx2` allows to create native excel charts using R. But overall I would suggest to export your results to Excel and re-create the charts in Excel.

Comment: "The journal I'm submitting is asking for MS excel graphs and editable in MS excel": personally, I'd look for another journal...

Comment: @stefan Kindly provide me a link or a code where these two library are used for the above purpose.

Comment: This is R. If a packages is referred to without source, look for it on CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/package=mschart and https://cran.r-project.org/package=openxlsx2. I am, however, with @Limey in this case: Look for a more serious journal if your problem and data are worth using a GAM on.

Answer (score 0):

The **mscharts** package has already been mentionned in the comments.

The **rvg** package is more flexible because it allows to render an Excel chart from any R plot (I think a ggplot is possible - to try).

Here is how to create a **dml** file:

```r
library(rvg)
dml_xlsx(file = "excelChart.dml")
plot(1:11, (-5:5)^2, type = "b", main = "Simple Example")
dev.off()
```

However I didn't found how one can visualize this file and how to convert it to a picture.

You can create an Excel sheet with an embedded chart as follows:

```r
library(rvg)
library(officer)
my_ws <- read_xlsx()
my_ws <- xl_add_vg(
  my_ws,
  sheet = "Sheet1",
  code = barplot(1:5, col = 2:6), width = 6, height = 6, left = 1, top = 2
)
fileout <- "excelChart.xlsx"
print(my_ws, target = fileout)
```

Then right-click on the chart and you can save it as a picture.